# Attachment to eCommerce email Template of kentico cms

Tags: e-commerce, payment, email-attachments, kentico, invoice

I am developing shopping website using kentico cms 9. In the website I want to send invoice to customer as a pdf attachment of email template (default kentico ecommerce email template).currently I am sending invoice in email body of email template and its Woking fine. But now I want to send Invoice as a pdf attachment as well as in email body also. Is this possible to send invoice with attachment of email template in kentico cms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can send email attachments using the API.  I believe this code is still valid for v11.

```
var emailTemplate = EmailTemplateProvider.GetEmailTemplate("yourtemplatename", "yoursitename");
MetaFileInfoProvider.GetMetaFiles(emailTemplate.TemplateID, "cms.emailtemplate", "Template", "", "");
```

Creating the invoice into a PDF is not out of the box though, you'd have to include a 3rd party tool to do that conversion for you.  Once you have the order, you can simply call `order.OrderInvoice` and it will render all the macros in the order invoice template and get you the HTML you need to send to a PDF to be created.

Comment: @Brendan thanks for the reply. Sorry I am new to kentico so I am confused where to write above code.as you suggested I converted invoice to PDF file and stored on my disk.but now i want to attach this PDF to eCommerce notification email which going to send after payment. again thanks for your reply. :)